# How to access shopify stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app

I'm building a shopify app with Node, React and Nextjs. One of the features allows the user to preview their widget changes in a preview window of the Thank You Page. I'm using shopify's theme classes so that the colors will be dynamic to each store's theme settings.

For example, a button in my project is drawing from the Shopify stylesheet: `<button className={"btn"}/>`

However, I'm having trouble maintaining an up to date stylesheet. Whenever the user makes a change in their shopify store, the sheet updates.

**Example:** The below sheet rendered a red button. Then the user changed the color of the button to green. The sheet changed accordingly.

`<link href="//cdn.shopify.com/app/services/61201907963/assets/129024491771/checkout_stylesheet/v2-ltr-edge-efa0a63b8eb42aba8cfba1e6c680e7fc-36" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Became (37 changed at the end):

`<link href="//cdn.shopify.com/app/services/61201907963/assets/129024491771/checkout_stylesheet/v2-ltr-edge-efa0a63b8eb42aba8cfba1e6c680e7fc-37" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I looked through Shopify's graphql to see if I could access the stylesheet, but with no luck. Really scratching my head on this.

How do I get access to the current stylesheet or alternatively, is there a better way to show theme settings (colors) in a shopify app preview?

Comment: What do you mean "how do I get access"? What are you trying to do? Is there code somewhere that you can share?

Comment: The style sheet pulls that type of information from the JSON file. If you create a developer account you can create stores that you mark "just playing around" (that's what Shopify calls it). Not sure if this helps. if you have the theme name I could tell you more. You may need to just have your style sheet refer to the JSON, as well.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for the reply! I made a more in depth post with better context on what I'm trying to accomplish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520194/how-to-show-a-preview-of-the-shopify-thank-you-page

Comment: @InquisitiveTom instead of a separate post - with no code - you should add that context here. I think Kat might be pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @Kat That seems exactly what I'm looking for! Currently working with the Dawn theme, but ideally the app would be able to pull JSON from any theme. Here's a preview to my "just playing around" theme: 4bl3pve06luq2ncr-61201907963.shopifypreview.com (Password: 123). If you refresh the preview and look in the console, the window.shopify object is available with more theme information. Curious, where does one access the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Some of this you probably know...for clarity:

In Shopify developers, go to your store.

Click on 'Online Store' in the left menu, under 'SALES CHANNELS'. A menu extends below, on the main screen you will see Themes, and near where it states 'Dawn', you'll see 'Customize'. Click on that button.

Once you are in the theme, at the top you will see the name of the theme, 'Live' and ... -- click on the dots, then click on 'Edit code.'

[image]

The menus in the edit code screen will open expanded, but you will find the following categories: layout, templates, sections, snippets, assets, config, and locales.

#### You will find the JSON files in config

- settings_data.json has the actuals
- settings_schema.json has the structure for settings_data.json

[image]

#### In the assets folder, you will find the CSS files

[image]

#### From here you'll see the variable linking to the JSON files

[image]